# How do I recover from a read DMA bootup error?

Tags: 12.04, boot

I am running 12.04 LTS, and almost every time I shut down my system, my root fails to mount on the next bootup, usually after an update.

In this particular case, I can see my filesystem when running on live CD, but every time I boot, I see the following sequence of messages cycle in an endless loop (process IDs removed):

```
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x24
ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:b0:f7:46/00:00:00:00:00/e0
         res 51/40:08:b0:f7:46/40:02:02:00:00/e0 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata1.00: status:{DRDY ERR}
ata1.00:error:{UNC}
end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 4650928
```

I boot off of a relatively new 60GB solid state disk drive, and in the past when I have run into this issue, I use fsck to detect and fix errors. But fsck runs clean on my partition, so i am uncertain how to approach the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to interpret these errors from syslog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9606/how-to-interpret-these-errors-from-syslog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an Input Output error at your Hard Disk sda part, at sector 4650928. 
You can boot from Ubuntu Live cd/dvd/usb, start Disks Utility, try to see the SMART data and test your sda disk.

[Possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13952/system-locking-up-with-suspicious-messages-about-hard-disk)

Comment: Disk utility claims the disk is healthy, although i am suspicious. The extended self-assessment (which should take "10s of minutes") finished in less than two with no errors. An attempted read-only benchmark failed on the first read attempt. The read error rate give assessment as "good", but shows a value of 16711680. Is there another utility I can try?

Comment: It seems that is a hardware problem. Some suggestions say to change HDD cables, others say to downgrade kernel version but could not find a quite solution.

Comment: One other issue: The system clock consitently comes up 2 hours slow every time I reboot. I've reset it in the BIOS setup and using various methods to reset time/date inside of a session opened with liveCD, but it consistently reverts ti the slower time upon restarting. Could this be related and is there a harder fix I could do?

Comment: ikorucu77--I did see that suggestion elsewhere I am inclined to try replacing the cables. The drive itself is a Corsair Nova 2, which I am now finding by trolling the forums was a particularly poor choice of an SSD. I will search ask ubuntu for advice regarding this issue, but any comments or ideas would be most welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The DMA read error was real. There was indeed a bad sector and replacing the SATA cables did not help. I finally tried to re-install from LiveCD, and the installation failed due to my bad disk drive. I originally went with an SSD because I wanted fast bootup, and was told that the Corsair Nova 2 was a good one, although more recent reviews (and this experience) refute that.

So the answer to this question should be marked as being due to a failed solid state drive.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem today. I unpluged sata cable and reconnected my hard drive to motherboard and it worked !