# E: Error: Opening the cache .... I/O error, dev sda, sector 71235640

Tags: 13.04, command-line, apt

I'm trying to run apt-update, but every time i run it and comes to end, it always has an error to the end saying

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file ...

I have tried running the following commands

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get clean

and after running this command again, the same message I still get.
sudo apt-get update

I decided to try it ove tty (F2) this is the message I get

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0721uxk36c
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0051uxk756

From the line I/O error thing.. is it telling me that the drive is getting bad?

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 in Dell D520

---

I've tried running the Disk utility SMART test, and all assessment seems to be okay. Only one attribute is failing which is the Airflow Temperature | 60C/140F.

With my issues above, is there anyway around to fix it? Can I still go on using my laptop. Cause I'm still far from getting a new laptop if the case is to be worst.

Answer (score 0):

yes that is what it is saying. You have a bad sector on your harddisk. Have you looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321277/how-do-i-recover-from-a-read-dma-bootup-error) Question? It also tells you how to run a disk-test to make sure.