# Ubuntu 16.04 Stuck in emergency mode and nothing works

Tags: boot, 16.04

When I started my laptop I found this message:

> "Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in,type "journalctl -xb" to
>   view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or
>   ^D to try again to boot into default mode."

I have tried commands <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or `systemctl default` but nothing happens. Here is what my screen looks like:

[image: Screen1]

[image: Screen2]
How can I solve this problem?

I checked my sda3, sda4 and sda6 drive the SMART data and showed the error. What else can I do or get from Ubuntu Live to home partitions to my files? Can I log in from the terminal to the disk home and copy files to another disk?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like a hard drive or disk controller hardware error - best case, loose cable; worst case dead drive. See [How do I recover from a read DMA bootup error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321277/how-do-i-recover-from-a-read-dma-bootup-error)

Comment: Drive sda6, sector 197398562, has a hard READ failure, and causing the drive to become not ready. Replace the HDD.

Comment: Can I get from Ubuntu Live to home partitions to my files? Can I log in from the terminal to the disk home and copy files to another disk?